# ERD Diagram relationship

Tags: erd

I have a diagram of entity-relationship. The question is how `A` relates to `D`. I understand how entities relate to each other but haven't found a good explanation of how something like this relates. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image: ERD Diagram]

Comment: A does not relates to D in any way. C has a relation with both A and D.

Comment: That makes the most sense to me. But this a practice question and the options are A)One-to-one, B) One-to-many, C)Many-to-one, D) Many-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a nice picture by briefly explaining the relationships:

[image]

So you once have a 1-to-0..* relationship and a 0..*-to-1 relationship.

**EDIT**:

I guess this is a many-to-many relationship. The diagram shows the representation in the database. And only for this relation a third entity is needed to store the keys.

Answer (score 0):

A does not relates to D in any way. C has a relation with both A and D.

Eg let say c entity is person.
D entity is number of phone numbers
A entity is number of houses.

As you can see a person can have multiple houses and phones but there is no relation between a house and phone.

Comment: That makes the most sense to me. But this a practice question and the options are A)One-to-one, B) One-to-many, C)Many-to-one, D) Many-to-many.